How do you upload OpenCypher formatted data to Neptune without supplying an ID?
I'm a little confused. OpenCypher MERGE statements do not require you to set an ID when loading data. This is ideal unless you want to externally track each node with its ID somewhere else.
However, neptune seems to require you to set some kind of ID when uploading OpenCyhper data. Is this actually required?
What is this ID, why do they do this and how am I supposed to accomplish this on massive sets of log data? Do I need an external lookup to store user emails with arbitrary IDs I've set, and deconflict that ID every time I add a new email? And all of that before I can even begin to uplpad data to neptune?
This makes absolutely no sense to me and I'm not sure why neptune requires this. It's making it impossible to upload our data.

Neptune has an underlying data model that uses unique IDs for every node and edge:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/feature-overview-data-model.html
The background here is that Neptune was originally built to support RDF/SPARQL and LPG/Gremlin.  openCypher support was added later.  So there are some concepts within Neptune's data model that may not be a direct translation from other datastores that support openCypher.
IDs, though, can be very beneficial.  Neptune supports very few constraints. One of the few that it does support is that every node/edge in the database must have a unique ID.  You can use this to your advantage to ensure uniqueness for identifiers that you may use for fast lookups.  For instance, if you wanted to ensure that every User vertex had a unique email address, you may want to use the email address as the ID for User vertices.
You can even take this a step further and create composite IDs from multiple aspects of your data to ensure uniqueness.  As an example, if you use email addresses elsewhere in your dataset, you may decide that user vertices would be better suited using an ID of "User_<email_address" (ex: "User_someone@somedomain.com").
